# How do you make the contents of a ListView an ArrayList?

Tags: java, listview, arraylist, javafx

I am trying to make a to do list javafx class and I'm using a list view to do it but I want to set the contents of the list view with an array list I made. SO basically that once I open the program you get a text field and button to add items to the arraylist which is the listview. Anyway I could replace the arraylist with the listview and just directly add the items to that? I'm a newbie programmer by the way.

```
package learning;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToDoList extends Application{

        private ArrayList<String> doList=new ArrayList<>();
        private String text="";
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("2DoList");

        TextField userTextField = new TextField();
        Button enter=new Button("Add");
        enter.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                text= userTextField.getText();
               doList.add(text);
               userTextField.setText("");
               text="";
            }
        });
        ListView<String> root=new ListView<String>((ObservableList)      doList);

        Scene scene=new Scene(root,250,500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `ObservableList` instead of an `ArrayList`:

```
private ObservableList<String> doList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

and then you can do

```
ListView<String> root=new ListView<String>(doList);
```

Comment: Thanks! Though when I do this the button and textfield arent visible. How do i fix this?

Comment: That's a different question. You should probably read some tutorials, though, instead of posting a forum question for each little step.

Comment: Please mark the question as correct if it helped. It will make it easier for other users to find it.